# pgAdmin import/export data greyed out

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin-4

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rnYat.png)

import/export data options are greyed out. How do i get them back

Comment: You can't Import/Export a language. The menu is context specific you will need to select a table to get a 'live' Import/Export.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver That doesn't make a lot of sense for "Import"

Comment: @Auspex, it does not make sense in either direction, a language is either created or dropped. There is no data involved.

Comment: I guess it does for PostGres, though. Other dbs let you actually import data as a new table.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver The question was unclear, but he didn't say anything about languages. He's clearly wanting to import data. I got here because I was doing the same, and surprised that PGAdmin couldn't import data and create a table in the same step.

Comment: And as I explained in my original comment you have to select a table not the Languages menu in order to get a 'live' Import/Export. There is no one step `create <table>/import data` process. The table needs to exist before hand.